# How do I fix these errors?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, djongo

I have an sqlite3 databased django app. I was trying to use djongo to switch to MongoDB Atlas. But I don't know how to fix these errors

I installed djongo

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-bs91f.mongodb.net/test?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE&retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        'USERNAME': '<username>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
    }
}
```

Thats the only thing I changed in settings.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 48, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 43, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/introspection.py", line 46, in get_table_list
    for c in cursor.db_conn.collection_names(False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 787, in collection_names
    nameOnly=True, **kws)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 725, in list_collections
    **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 675, in _list_collections
    session=tmp_session)["cursor"]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 555, in _command
    client=self.__client)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 584, in command
    user_fields=user_fields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 158, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unsupported type in filter
```

I keep getting these errors. I don't know how to fix them

Comment: Can you give some more details? What triggers this error?

Comment: Please show us the **full** error traceback, including the actual error in the last line.

Comment: I edited it now to include the complete traceback

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your password (and login maybe) with the package [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to connect with Pymongo :

```
'password': urllib.parse.quote_plus("<password>")
```

Comment: I'm not using any special characters though

Answer (score 0):

if you use a special character in a password then it's given you an error.use a  [parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) or change your password

Comment: The password doesn't have any special characters